# How do you reposition a Storyboard with Xcode 6 and Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode6, osx-yosemite-beta

I installed the latest Xcode and Yosemite betas several days ago and have noticed a feature of Yosemite seems to be its not possible (by design or bug?) to click on a a scroll bar and drag.

This was an irritation but now I'm trying to navigate within a storyboard and there's no apparent way of moving around - there's no navigation bars, there's no arrows, pressing arrows on a MacBook keyboard does nothing, its not possible to click within the story board and move it around, there's no zoom/de-zoom button to expand/collape the Storyboard.

I've been scratching my head then getting increasingly irritated, I just can't see any way of repositioning a storyboard with Xcode and thus I can't do a thing at the moment - there are view controllers in my Storyboard not displayed on screen and I just can't get to them!

Comment: Dragging the scroll bars works fine for me: you might want to reinstall Yosemite because that appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving around the Storyboard works the same way that it has always worked: drag with two fingers on the trackpad or click and drag the scroll bars.

If neither of those are working for you, it's a bug and you need to [report it](//bugreport.apple.com). Also consider reinstalling Yosemite and/or Xcode because I am unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Looks like it must be a bug in Yosemite, I re-started the OS and scroll bars worked fleetingly for several seconds but then stopped (i.e. not possible to click on them or drag them up and down with a mouse). And its not just Xcode I have a problem with its other apps such as Safari.

Comment: @Woofbeans I'd report it, then: scrolling is working fine for me on beta 3.